# How to disable the message "Dependee ... is newer than depender ..." with CMake

Tags: cmake

During compilation, cmake shows this kind of message :
"Dependee  is newer than depender "
to explain why a file needs to be recompiled.

How can I get rid of this message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, the problem is in Buildroot. The root makefile export VERBOSE environment variable (the variable is empty, but Cmake only tests if the variable is defined, not its value).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can define CMAKE_NO_VERBOSE environment variable to suppress generating detailed info from cmake. You can also call make with argument CMAKE_NO_VERBOSE=1 which will have the same effect.

Comment: That will lose other _relevant_ information like the compiler commands as well and is therefore discouraged.